# dynamic imports with variable path in CRA

Tags: javascript, reactjs, create-react-app

Anyone know why can't you use template literals with dynamic imports in create react app 
The below wont work but if I just put the path right in as a string it works.

Example: this throws an error **Uncaught (in promise) Error: Cannot find module '../components/test/page1/data'**

```
useEffect(() => {
    const folder = "test";
    const id = "page1";
    const path = `../components/${folder}/${id}/data`;
    import(path).then((res) => {
      console.log("module = ", res.default);
    });
  }, []);
```

**Works**

```
useEffect(() => {
    import("../components/test/page1/data").then((res) => {
      console.log("module = ", res.default);
    });
  }, []);
```

Comment: It worked for me. looks fine.

Comment: I believe this is a restriction in Webpack and some other tools. It is not a restriction of the ESM spec and there are loaders, like SystemJS, that can handle it.

Comment: Check https://webpack.js.org/api/module-methods/#dynamic-expressions-in-import

Comment: I’m using CRA so not sure I have access to Webpack files.

Comment: @chandan-kr-jha You were able to get the first emails working ?  Or you mean you got the second example working ?